# How do I add multiple groups to a user with the Atlassian Crowd REST API?

Tags: rest, atlassian-crowd

I see on [this page](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CROWDDEV/JSON+Requests+and+Responses) that I can add a user to a group by POSTing to `/user/group/direct?username=USERNAME`, however that looks like you can only add one group to the user at a time. The API calls I will be making may require that I add several and it would be to nice put all the groups into one POST request. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current resources only allow adding one group membership at a time, either through the user or group resources. You will need to make several calls.

There is an open feature request ([CWD-2378](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CWD-2378)) to add bulk operations to the resources.